Math programs in Russia and post-Soviet states - how do they compare to US?
I studied math in college and also took a few years of Russian. For a time, I was looking for a way of living in Russia post-graduation (well before the recent war) and I asked one of my professors, who spent about half the year in Russia, about entering a math graduate program there. She said I had no chance, as a high school graduate in Russia knew about as much math as someone with a math undergrad from my college, a well-regarded school in US, a but liberal arts college so not as intense of focus on major -- the math program was designed to be completable with only 12 courses for someone who hadn't taken any calculus in high school.
I never ended up going to grad school (in the US or Russia) but I have thought about this comment occasionally since then when I hear something about Russia and math. My assumption is that the professor doesn't even know what math looks like after calculus, and that she was pulling things out of somewhere, but I'm curious whether anyone knows more. My impression has been that in Russia there is/was a much greater emphasis on applied mathematics compared to 'pure' mathematics (not sure whether that's a loaded term, but hopefully you understand what I mean).
While studying for a few months in Russia, a friend I made showed me some sort of standardized high school mathematics exam, I think a college entrance exam. I can't remember any specifics but I think it used math that is taught in US schools but in significantly more difficult / complex ways than say, the SAT or even the SAT subject test (RIP). Based on that, my guess is that Russian high school students on average have a higher comprehension of the subject material, but that what the material is is not far off from the US. As for how a college math program in Russia compares to the US, I have no idea. I'd be interested in anything anyone with more experience or knowledge can share about the similarities and differences across high school, undergraduate, and potentially graduate programs.

I think this question is for https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/
